# How should I covert my Java code into Jmeter BeanShell Sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I have small piece of Java code, which i have to incorporate into Jmeter to call a particular Jar file that contains OAuth Authentication.

```
Java Code:-
package Name1;
import Service;
public class OAuth {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String requestPayload ="";
    OAuth service = new OAuth("${Key1}", "${Key2}")
    .setRequestTokenURL("${URL1}")
    .setAccessTokenURL("${URL2}")
    .setAccessResourceURL("${URL3}")
    .setRequestorId("${Email}")
    .setScope("${Status}");     
    String[] authenticatedAccessToken = service.getAuthenticatedAccessToken();      
    String resourceResponse = service.accessResource(requestPayload, authenticatedAccessToken);     
    System.out.println(resourceResponse);               
}
```

Bean Shell Sampler code is as follows

We tried this code, but it is not working.

```
import Service;
key = vars.getObject("${AppKey}");
secret = vars.getObject("${SecretKey}");
Email = vars.getObject("${Email}");
Scope = vars.getObject("${Scope}");
requestPayload =vars.getObject("");

OAuth service = new OAuth(key, secret);
service.setRequestTokenURL("${URL1}");
service.setAccessTokenURL("${URL2}");
service.setAccessResourceURL("${URL3}}");
service.setRequestorId(${Email});
service.setScope(${Scope});
authenticatedAccessToken = service.getAuthenticatedAccessToken();
resourceResponse = service.accessResource(requestPayload, authenticatedAccessToken);
SampleResult.setResponseData(resourceResponse);
```

Can some one help us in correcting us as what went wrong in the piece of code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that .jar file(s) providing Service namespace live in JMeter classpath (usually /lib folder of your JMeter installation) and you restarted JMeter to pick them up.

Try the following:

```
import Service;
key = vars.getObject("AppKey");
secret = vars.getObject("SecretKey");
Email = vars.getObject("Email");
Scope = vars.getObject("Scope");
requestPayload =vars.getObject("");

OAuth service = new OAuth(key, secret);
service.setRequestTokenURL(vars.get("URL1"));
service.setAccessTokenURL(vars.get("URL2"));
service.setAccessResourceURL(vars.get("URL3");
service.setRequestorId(Email);
service.setScope(Scope);
authenticatedAccessToken = service.getAuthenticatedAccessToken();
resourceResponse = service.accessResource(requestPayload, authenticatedAccessToken);
SampleResult.setResponseData(resourceResponse);
```

- when you use `vars.get()` or `vars.getObject()` you don't need to surround variable name with `${}`
- when you refer previously defined variable (like `Email`) you also don't need these figure brackets

Few tips on debugging Beanshell script:

- if you add `debug();` directive at the very beginning of your script - you'll see detailed debugging information in stdout
- if you wrap your code into "try" block and set "catch" block like:

  ```
  catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Somewhing wrong: " , ex);
  }
  ```

  you'll see the stacktrace in *jmeter.log* file

You can also consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as

- it is 100% Java compatible (including generics, switch on strings, try-with-resources, etc.)
- it implements [Compilable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html) interface resulting in better performance

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more detailed explanation, instructions on installing groovy scripting engine and scripting best practices.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the piece of code, I tried the above code but i am not getting the header value that i was supposed to get using eclipse. i checked all the Jar files that i gave to my java code that is working fine in eclipse.  If i put ${} symbol then only i am able to pass value to my script. otherwise it i am able to see only 'Appkey' or 'Email' is getting updated in the request that we are sending and not their values that i am passing through a .csv file. I am trying it now with JSR223 sampler, let me update you after that.

Comment: I tried to use "try" block and set "catch" to but i am able see the below error [ 2015/12/31 10:43:30 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script7.groovy: 3: Unknown type: IMPORT at line: 3 column: 1. File: Script7.groovy @ line 3, column 1.
   import oauth.OAuth; ]